# Не добавляются сцены в Build

Tags: unity3d

Недавно начал учить Юнити, вот проблема: новые сцены ‘’’Level 2’’’ и ‘’’Finish’’’ не добавляются в Scenes In Build, что делать?
Если точнее, для перехода между сцен нужно чтобы сцена была добавлена в билд, но когда я нажимаю на add open scenes, моя сцена не добавляется.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Я уже решил, нужно открыть сцену только тогда добавлять ее.

Comment: Впрочем, в названии кнопки все написано было)